# WSO2 Identity Server device authentication(cookie based) not working while accessing application from internet

Tags: json, cookies, wso2, multi-factor-authentication, wso2-identity-server

I am using WSO2 identity server(wso2is-km 5.7) for multifactor authentication for an application.

I have set policy as:
First time login to application: Basic Authentication + email OTP.

This sets a device cookie in the browser, so when I logout from the application and try to login to the same application again it should just ask me for basic authentication.

Second and further login to application:Basic authentication(no email otp this time).

This whole policy works fine when i am carrying out this activity from intranet(Corporate network) but the same doesn't work if I try to login from internet(we have put WSO2 behind WAF[web application firewall]). Here i am being prompted for email otp even on second and further login to the application, meaning the device cookie is not being correctly set here.

Please refer the error below:[[ERROR](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cBl7q.png)]
Error occurred when converting cookie value to JSON.Unexpected token END OF FILE at position 993

My guess is the cookie being set in the internet case is not proper(appended with some garbage value during SSL offloading at WAF).
How do i reslove this issue??

Comment: Let's first verify the browser is sending the cookie correctly by checking the `Cookie` header of the request. Then we can check the cookie received by Identity Server by printing the `Cookie` header in the HTTP Access Logs. Print it by changing the following config. <IS_HOME>/repository/conf/tomcat/catalina-server.xml          <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve" directory="${carbon.home}/repository/logs"
                      prefix="http_access_" suffix=".log"
                      pattern="%h %l %u %t %r %s %b %{Referer}i %{User-Agent}i %{Cookie}i"/>

Comment: Adding above will print the Cookie header in the HTTP access log. Check if WSO2 receives anything different from what browser has sent.

Comment: You can try using the network tracer of the browser or some plugin like SAML-tracer to trace the network calls. Check if the /commonauth POST request that submits the email OTP receives a 302 response code and Set-Cookie header for commonAuthId cookie. And check the Location header of this response. Next thing you need to check is what are the cookies your browser sends in your next login request. Update the answer with these info.